# Equivalent to LastGoodBuildLabel in TFS 2017 Build

Tags: tfsbuild, tfvc, tfs-2017

I just recently came back to a .NET development team after a few years away.   I'm trying to get caught up with things that have changed over the years.  Our organization still runs TFS 2017.  Our build definitions are all converted to vNEXT.  Back when we had XAML builds, we were able to set the build property LastGoodBuildDefinition to tell a build definition how far back to go to to associate ChangeSets and Work Items with the build.  Does anyone know how to do the equivalent in TFS 2017 Build?  I'm unable to find it in Microsoft's documentation.

Seached through Microsoft's documentation, looked through build definition, unable to find a predefined parameter to match the old functionality.